# add languages to oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, persian

I have some problems with Oracle 11 g DB (Enterprise)  I want it can read all **languages** or at least Persian (Farsi) . As you can see in this image , DB already shows something mad instead Persian words SO  How can we set or add languages on it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCrOc.png

I'm not familiar with Oracle but my boss wants it work soon.

Comment: Oracle supports Farsi. But it's easy to make a mistake when importing data or when displaying or exporting it. How exactly did you import the data? And what tool are you using to display the data? And with what character set did you set up the database (`select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'`)?

Comment: In fact I have some old exported versions and I'm not sure about every thing is imported in true ways or not !? BUT I think this problem might be because encoding ( I think it should have something like UTF8 in sql ) How can I set ENCODING ? @Codo

Comment: Data is showing by Fire fox browser in WIN server 2008 r2  if it was what you asked

Comment: There are thousands of ways to import data. And "Firefox" just tells half of the story of how you display the data. Are you using Firefox to connect to Oracle Enterprise Manager? Anyway, I strongly recommend you install the latest version of Oracle SQL Developer (it's free) and use it to create a table, manually insert a few rows and display them. If it works there, you can then isolate the other problems.

Comment: See my answer here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584283/when-insert-persian-character-in-oracle-db-i-see-the-question-mark/24597374#24597374][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584283/when-insert-persian-character-in-oracle-db-i-see-the-question-mark/24597374#24597374

Comment: Thanks ; I still working on it ...