# Losing special characters on insert

Tags: sql, oracle, xpath, utf-8, osb

I am using oracle 11g and trying to insert a string containing special UTF8 characters eg '(ε- c'.  The NLS character sets for the databse are...

```
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET    WE8ISO8859P1
```

when I copy and paste the above string into a `NVARCHAR` field it works fine.

if I execute the below I get an upside down question mark in the field

```
insert into title_debug values ('(ε- c');
```

where title debug table consists of a single `NVARCHAR2(100)` field called title.

I have attempted to assign this string to a `NVARCHAR2(100)` variable then iserting this. And also attempted all the different CAST / CONVERT ect functions I can find and nothing is working.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE

I have executed

```
select dump(title, 1016), dump(title1, 1016)
into v_title, v_title1
from dual
```

where title is the string passed in as a varchar and title1 is the string passed in as a NVarchar.

Unsuprisingly the encodings come through as WE8ISO8859P1 and AL16UTF16. but on both the ε comes through as hex 'BF'.  This is the upside down Question mark.

My only thought left is to try and pass this through as a raw and then do something with it. However I have not yet been able to figure out how to convert the string into a acceptable format with XQuery (OSB).

Continued thanks for assistance.

Comment: You need to tell Oracle what encoding your data is using. The mechanism depends entirely on how you run queries: SQL*Plus? SQL Developer? Java code? PHP code?

Comment: Hi the data is being feed from the Oracle Service bus.  So comming in through a JCA adapter.  The Adapter by default encodes the data as UTF8. I have tried through via getting OSB to direclty insert into the table and also through passing it to a procedure via both varchar and nvarchar parameters.  I have also tried passing it in as a raw and converting all to with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our DBA found the solution to this issue.  The answer lay in a setting on the dbc connection on the bus to tell it to convert utf8 to NChar.

On The connection pool page add the following lines to the Properties box.

oracle.jdbc.convertNcharLiterals=true
oracle.jdbc.defaultNchar=true

this will allow you to be able to insert into NVarchar2 fields while maintaining the utf8 characters.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I did a test with '(ε- c'. And i have not encountered any problems.

If you can i advice you to change your character set for :

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET            AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET      AL16UTF16
```

And Oracle recommendation for all new deployment is the Unicode character set AL32UTF8.

Because it's flexible globalization support and is a universal character set

reg,

Comment: Oracle is not flexible at all with encodings. If you change it, you have to change it for the complete database instance. Whatever, of course it's possible to submit non-ASCII characters to a UTF-16 column (that's the whole point). The OP forgot to set the connection encoding, but we have no idea so far about his environment so there's no way to give a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a small project within a large database so there is no chance of changing the NLS Settings but thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

First verify the data is being stored correctly, then use the correct NLS_LANG settings. See my answer to this question:

[when insert persian character in oracle db i see the question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584283/when-insert-persian-character-in-oracle-db-i-see-the-question-mark/24597374#24597374)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but as stated in the question my enviroment will display the value correctly when copy pased directly into the field in the table (using toad).  But when I try and automate by using an insert it fails.