# Oracle SQL loader: Convert foreign chars to English

Tags: sql, oracle, character-encoding, sql-loader

I'm using SQL loader to load a data file into an Oracle table.  The database has a character set of US7ASCII.  Some of the records in the data file contain European special characters such as é or ü or î.  When they are loaded into the table, the results are weird with 2 strange icons (like black diamond with an arrow inside).

Is there anyway to get SQL loader to load the nearest English equivalent instead?  So the é would be loaded as e, the ü would be loaded as u and the î would be loaded as i?

Comment: They are probably not in SQL is Unicode.  As for converting to "English" a program would probably be best to use a program.  They are call diacritic,

Comment: Do you have string `CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252` in control file?

Comment: Frisbee - I am unsure of the charset of the incoming file.  I have asked the supplier to confirm this.

Comment: Egor - I don't have any CHARACTERSET in my control file at the moment.  I am now running with some tests of different CHARACTERSET values to see what difference this makes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First establish what is actually being stored. Use the Oracle SQL DUMP function, e.g. SELECT dump ( colname, 16 ) from table.

This will return the HEX code for the data in colname.

If the hex code matches the hex code (od -h) of the input then the data is stored correctly, and the issue you have is translation on display. See my answer below for how to deal with this:

[when insert persian character in oracle db i see the question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584283/when-insert-persian-character-in-oracle-db-i-see-the-question-mark/24597374#24597374)

The more likely issue you have is your database character US7ASCII cannot cope with extended character sets.