# How to extract images stored in LONG / CLOB datatype from ORACLE 11.2g?

Tags: python, oracle, clob

I have a very old oracle database dump from year 2006 that has images stored in LONG datatype. It seems that binary data is stored in the character type column. How do I export those images to .jpeg files?

I have restored the database to Oracle 11.2g. Everything works perfectly except the images. I have created a new table to use CLOB instead of LONG Datatype and moved one record to that table, because altering the table to use CLOB was failing with error SQL Error: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype.

```
CREATE TABLE image_table_NEW AS SELECT TO_LOB(sign_area) \
sign_area FROM image_table where rownum=1;
```

Then read the data using python,

```
import cx_Oracle
sql = 'select SIGN_AREA from xxx.image_table_NEW where rownum<2'
imagePath = '/home/amrutraj/Desktop/image.jpeg'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@//IP:port/sid')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchone()
strBlob=row[0].read()
imageFile = open(imagePath,'wb') # also tried with just w
imageFile.write(strBlob)
imageFile.close()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

A file named image.jpeg is generated, but its not readable. Its giving error 'Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x3f 0x3f)'

Above code works perfectly with the BLOB datatype columns.

EDIT:
Source Database Character set : UNKNOWN
Database Character set : AL32UTF8

EDIT 2: (17 feb 2019)
I tried using DBMS_LOB.converttoblob in sqldeveloper with this script https://oracle-base.com/dba/script?category=miscellaneous&file=clob_to_blob.sql  BUT kept getting error '06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"'.

[SCREENSHOT OF THE CLOB DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvzPP.png)

Comment: Do you know what character set the source database used?  What character set is your Oracle 11.2 database using? Can you look at the contents of the `LONG` column - do they mostly contain `?` characters?  (My concern is that the image data has been corrupted by a character-set conversion as part of the import into your Oracle 11.2 database.)

Comment: Source Database Character set : UNKNOWN,
Database Character set : AL32UTF8,
Yes. It contains lots of ?s. Should I try to restore the database dump in older versions of oracle?

Comment: Make sure to set the `NLS_LANG` environment variable in your python environment to an appropriate value. If on output you get `?` in place of multibyte characters it is likely you need to match up your NLS_LANG to the database. I would suggest you use SQL Developer top inspect the data in the LONG column. LONGs are fiendishly difficult to work with; you cant run `DUMP()` on them to see what the actual data is.

Comment: I tried to use DBMS_LOB.converttoblob procedure and failed as mentioned in the edits above. In my oracle instance  NLS_LANGUAGE has value  ENGLISH. I tried setting os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = ".AL32UTF8"  And os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = "ENGLISH" in python. But no change. Lots of ?s.

Comment: I just confirmed that the source database also uses Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 I am using 11.2.0.4.0 at my place. So I don't think data got changed while importing the dump. I think the data contains all the information, I just dont know why on saving it as a jpeg, its getting corrupted.

Comment: NLS_LANG ... you are not setting it correctly. It has two parts: `TERRITORY.CHARSET`. . See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584283/when-insert-persian-character-in-oracle-db-i-see-the-question-mark/24597374#24597374 .

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's AL32UTF8. But I did set os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = "AL32UTF8" and still not being able to get the image. I did, however try, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW. And I think I am going somewhere with it. I will keep you posted.

Comment: Dealing with this data as a CLOB is the wrong way to go. Image files are binary data, not character data. The first step is figuring out how these images are stored in the LONG in the first place. Of course you're going to get lots of ?s, because your binary source data will have lots of byte sequences that are not valid UTF8 characters. And if you don't know if your LONG was originally stored as UTF8, you're going to corrupt the data even further.

Comment: Without wading into the bigger picture (which other people are handling just fine), if you set NLS_LANG to just a character set (without the country & territory), you need to prefix the char set with a leading full stop, e..g `os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = ".AL32UTF8" ` but you would probably be better using the `encoding` parameter when you call `connect()`